# Identify inefficient precompiled headers in C++

Tags: c++, compilation, precompiled-headers

We have precompiled headers, list of headers in pch.h and I'd like refine that list because it seems inefficient. I'm using CMake+MSVC to compile our project.
We have single pch.h file and multiple targets (both shared and static)

I'm using vcperf to profile the compilation time and follow these steps
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/faster-cpp-builds-simplified-a-new-metric-for-time/

What would be efficient strategy to spot ineffective headers in my pch.h list? Is vcperf emiting some data that could be interpreted so that I can understand that some header can be kicked out of my pch.h file?

Comment: As I remember, MSVC only allows one single precompiled header. Which tends to turn into some kind of "god header" which includes a lot of things that aren't needed everywhere. That could worsen your build-times since a change in one of those headers will force a rebuilt of a lot of unrelated source files. Keep the precompiled header to its bare minimum, and include `<windows.h>` and perhaps one or two other system header files that are commonly used by your projects. Nothing more.

Comment: *"precompiled headers done by somebody else"* - ¿Does this even work properly? I mean in order to use precompiled headers your current header files, toolchain and settings must match those used to create those headers, which is rather unlikely. And i'm not sure what is the meaning of "ineffective headers" in this context. If you are trying to improve build times then you should focus on compilation from scratch rather then digging into some of the precompiled headers. So this question seems to me an XY problem.

Comment: Firstly, I wouldn't use precompiled headers supplied by "somebody else" without good reason.  And (if using precompiled headers at all (personally, I often do not)) it is best to be very selective about what headers to precompile.

Comment: @LukasT Before you go down that avenue which can take a lot of trial and error actually, are you able to target C++20 or preferably C++23 (or will you be able to in the not-too-distant future)? If so I'd first suggest reviewing [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/compare-inclusion-methods?view=msvc-170) (and "_See also_" section at bottom), which you should read anyway. It will likely impact your decisions and in fact, those of most developers soon (if not already).

Comment: _As I remember, MSVC only allows one single precompiled header_
Yes, we have single precompiled header pch.h and it includes N headers. I'd like to optimize that list

_Does this even work properly? I mean in order to use precompiled headers your current header files, toolchain ..._

I mean the work was done by other developer and I don't think he used scientific method with vcperf and profiled properly, but he made a set of includes by some strange decision patterns. Some choices are good, some are bad. I want to identify the includes that are inefficient.

Comment: _If you are trying to improve build times then you should focus on compilation from scratch_

I see, basically start over: turn off the current precompiled headers and build a new list of headers  to be included in our precompiled header using vcperf. I was hoping that that vcperf could help me identify headers that are inefficient in current pch.h since I assume over time the list might again get dated to small degree.

Comment: _Firstly, I wouldn't use precompiled headers supplied by "somebody else" without good reason_

I worded it badly: I meant other developer on our project no longer with us using naive strategy where I can see that he made strange choices. 

_are you able to target C++20 or preferably C++23_

I see, modules, right? Thank you! We are not there yet unfortunately and we probably won't be for next 2 years (C++23 at least, I hear C++20 is not yet there).

Comment: @Lukas Modules (C++20) are still very new to most of course, and "*import std*" (and "*import std.compat*") even newer (C++23), but at least MSFT supports them now, and I've used both (in fact, there's a fairly simple technique for migrating headers to modules but that's another story). Many shops won't be using either for a while still, but since they're supposed to be a lot faster in theory, you might want to start thinking about it sooner rather than later. It seems likely that headers will (finally) start becoming a thing of the past soon (not that they'll be be disappearing anytime soon).